# Including HTML files locally / templating?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm writing a web application / UI for a game that's done purely in HTML. A lot of things are in common like the top bar, menu bar, pop-up friends UI and the like. Normally, something like this is done with server-side includes? I've heard document.write is inherently evil - so what's the options client sided?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty questionable idea...but if I HAD to do it I'd probably use an object that serves as a map where the keys were ids (or selectors) and the the values were HTML (or templates) and then use JS to populate the key matching elements with the values (season to taste).

Comment: @MattWhipple What else would you suggest? It's a hobby project - so it's mallable. The game UI is written completely in HTML; and runs locally in the application.

Comment: I'd recommend finding anything available to do it before being served to the client.  You could find a solution that allows you to assemble the pages and keep everything static but manage the snippets individually.  A long time ago I did something similar using sed, and I think HTML editors like Dreamweaver usually do this kind of thing.

Comment: Right - a templating system of some sort?

Comment: Yeah, templating that is more of a pre-processor so you're still left with static, plain HTML output.

Comment: I'm okay with static output - it sits on the client anyway after all. I just need a way to organize everything locally so it's not a bunch of copy-pasta. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this:

1. Client-side Templating - check out [Moustache](http://mustache.github.io/) and [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)
2. AJAX - You could load the header/footer asynchronously and render them around your content (or vice-versa, create your site as a single-page application, loading the wrapper first, then loading the page content asynchronously and inserting that into the wrapper).
3. iFrames / Framesets - Old-school, but it will do what you want, more or less.

Comment: The Apache stuff is out of the question - this is local. There's no web server involved.

Comment: Understood, well you could also use a client-side templating framework like moustache or handlebars

Comment: Sounds like a templating system does more or less what I need.